# How to get Hashmap list value

Tags: android, hashmap, adapter, expandablelistview

This is my tryout for expandable listview and i want to set text in adapter but its not works for me

```
 listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                            JSONArray jsonObject = response.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject object1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(i);
                                listDataHeader.add(object1.getString("title"));
                                List<String> lease_offer = new ArrayList<String>();
                                lease_offer.add(object1.getString("name"));
                                lease_offer.add(object1.getString("tips"));
                                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), lease_offer);
                                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

Adapter:-

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                     HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
            WebView ImageCild = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Imagess);



            ImageCild.loadData(childText,"text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
            return convertView;
        }
```

But i cant understand which data are come in child text if i have 2 textview then how to retrieve particular value from hashmap?

```
txtListChild.setText(childText.getname());
```

How to set like these in hashmap?

Please help me i am using first time hashmap in android

Comment: You are setting position as key in Hasmap   listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), lease_offer); and list as its value. 
So simply get value from hasp by passing position as key.
e.g. _listDataChild.get(position) it will return list which you passes while adding in hashmap.
If my comment is relevant to you please vote up.

Comment: please help me in code

Comment: Try above given examples in you getChildview method. It will work.

Comment: please tell me `_listDataChild.get(position)` which postion i cant understand please write the code for me

Comment: Groupposition  should be passed.